# Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor has only single cpu support?

Tags: powershell, wmi, perfmon

I want to read out the utilization of all cores with powershell. I have tried following command

```
(Get-WmiObject -Query "select Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor") | foreach-object { write-host "$($_.Name): $($_.PercentProcessorTime)" };
```

but this only returns the utilization of the logical cores of cpu0. I haven't found a way to get it also for the second processor in the system. Has someone a solution for it?

In my example i have two Intel Xeon E5-2697 v4 with 72 logical cores overall. Task Manager shows me all cores with correct utilization, but the above command returns only 36. I have attached a image which shows perfmon with only 36 cores [perfmon image](http://kfx.de/share/wdf88.png).

Comment: You do not need to iterate that in a foreach loop. Directly select the corresponding properties' values. `Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor | select PSComputerName,Name,PercentProcessorTime`

Answer (score 1):

No need for iteration

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor | select PSComputerName,Name,PercentProcessorTime
```

should work.